# What I'm supposed to do with this Chainsaw?

Tags: maniac-mansion

In the old Maniac Mansion Game for the commodore 64, you could find a Chainsaw in the kitchen.

I never found any use for it!

I always wondered what I'm supposed to do with it?

Is there anyone who could make it work? Maybe Bernard could "cook" some gas?

Comment: Don't cut yourself!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course some Lucasarts humour:

> The game featured some notorious red
>   herrings, such as a chainsaw for which
>   there was no fuel, despite many
>   wishful rumours to the contrary. In
>   one of the in-jokes that are a
>   hallmark of the LucasArts adventure
>   games, the second SCUMM game, Zak
>   McKracken and the Alien Mindbenders,
>   contains some fuel "for chainsaws
>   only", but no chainsaws.

via [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maniac_Mansion#Gameplay)